# Slick Slider picture size is bigger than the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making the slick slider with lightbox. Everthing is fine except for the full browerser screen size.
When I maximize the browser screen size, the whole content is bigger the screen and cannot see anything.
However, it works fine when I minimize the browser screen size like the phone screen ratio. I am finding the problem and still can't find which is causing this screen size issue.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me to solve this screen size issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.slider-thumbnails').slick({
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider',
    focusOnSelect: true
  });

  $('.slider').slick({
    infinite: false,
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
    asNavFor: '.slider-thumbnails',
  });
});

<
script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.3/js/lightbox.min.js"
integrity = "sha512-k2GFCTbp9rQU412BStrcD/rlwv1PYec9SNrkbQlo6RZCf75l6KcC3UwDY8H5n5hl4v77IDtIPwOk9Dqjs/mMBQ=="
crossorigin = "anonymous" > < /script>
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background: #dedede;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.container {
  max-width: 900px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #f5f5f5;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .product {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .product-description {
    margin-left: 36px;
  }
}


/* Main Slider */

.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: solid 9px #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.slider .slick-slide {}

.slider .slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}


/* make button larger and change their positions */

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: 5px;
}

.slick-next {
  right: 5px;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/* General slick slider styling */

.slick-slide:focus,
.slick-slide:focus {
  outline: none;
  /* remove default outline when on :focus */
}


/* hide dots and arrow buttons when slider is not hovered */

.slick-slider:not(:hover) .slick-arrow,
.slick-slider:not(:hover) .slick-dots {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* transition effects for opacity */

.slick-arrow {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  product-images {
    width: 50%;
  }
}


/* Thumbnails Slider */

.slider-thumbnails {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.slider-thumbnails .slick-slide {
  padding: 15px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}

.slider-thumbnails .slick-slide:focus img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.slider-thumbnails .slick-slide img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border: solid 5px #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-out;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


/* Loading effects for main slider */

.slider {
  background: url(img/tail-spin.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.slider img.slick-loading {
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider img {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.slider .slick-loading:after {
  content: 'loading'
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.3/css/lightbox.css" integrity="sha512-Woz+DqWYJ51bpVk5Fv0yES/edIMXjj3Ynda+KWTIkGoynAMHrqTcDUQltbipuiaD5ymEo9520lyoVOo9jCQOCA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Slick Slider</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-images">

      <div class="slider">
        <div>
          <a href="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3663057.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox">
            <img data-lazy="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3663057.jpg" alt="Image 1">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661267.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox">
            <img data-lazy="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661267.jpg" alt="Image 2">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661194.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox">
            <img data-lazy="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661194.jpg" alt="Image 3">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661227.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox">
            <img data-lazy="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661227.jpg" alt="Image 4">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661259.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox">
            <img data-lazy="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661259.jpg" alt="Image 5">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661265.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox">
            <img data-lazy="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661265.jpg" alt="Image 6">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slider-thumbnails">
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3663057.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 1">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661267.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 2">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661194.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 3">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661227.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 4">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661259.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 5">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661265.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 6">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="product-description">
      <h2>Product Title</h2>
      <p>
        <strong>Price:</strong> Rp 120.000
        <br />
        <strong>Brand:</strong> Lorem Ipsum
        <br />
        <strong>Weight:</strong> 2kg
      </p>
      <h3>Description</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
      <p>
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a viewport meta tag like `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`?

Comment: @asyncawait yes i have

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Just add a width value to ```.product-images``` as shown in the answer below, that will fix it.

Comment: @prettyInPink got it. Thanks a lot I really appreciate your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue is your `css`,
flex setting:
`flex-direction: row;`is causing the issue in this case.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .product {
    /*flex-direction: row; --> THIS SEEMS TO CAUSE THE ISSUE */
  }
}
```

You can still have it in a row for larger screens, but you will have to set a width for the `.product-images` element, like say 50%.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.slider-thumbnails').slick({
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider',
    focusOnSelect: true
  });

  $('.slider').slick({
    infinite: false,
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
    asNavFor: '.slider-thumbnails',
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background: #dedede;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.container {
  max-width: 900px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #f5f5f5;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .product {
    /*flex-direction: row; --> THIS SEEMS TO CAUSE THE ISSUE */
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .product-description {
    margin-left: 36px;
  }
  .product-images {
    width: 50%; /* include a width value */
  }
}


/* Main Slider */

.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border: solid 9px #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.slider .slick-slide {}

.slider .slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
}


/* make button larger and change their positions */

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: 5px;
}

.slick-next {
  right: 5px;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/* General slick slider styling */

.slick-slide:focus,
.slick-slide:focus {
  outline: none;
  /* remove default outline when on :focus */
}


/* hide dots and arrow buttons when slider is not hovered */

.slick-slider:not(:hover) .slick-arrow,
.slick-slider:not(:hover) .slick-dots {
  opacity: 0;
}


/* transition effects for opacity */

.slick-arrow {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  product-images {
    width: 50%;
  }
}


/* Thumbnails Slider */

.slider-thumbnails {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.slider-thumbnails .slick-slide {
  padding: 15px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}

.slider-thumbnails .slick-slide:focus img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.slider-thumbnails .slick-slide img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border: solid 5px #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  transition: box-shadow 0.3s ease-out;
  border-radius: 3px;
}


/* Loading effects for main slider */

.slider {
  background: url(img/tail-spin.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.slider img.slick-loading {
  opacity: 0;
}

.slider img {
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.slider .slick-loading:after {
  content: 'loading'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.3/css/lightbox.css" integrity="sha512-Woz+DqWYJ51bpVk5Fv0yES/edIMXjj3Ynda+KWTIkGoynAMHrqTcDUQltbipuiaD5ymEo9520lyoVOo9jCQOCA==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Slick Slider</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="product">
    <div class="product-images">

      <div class="slider">
        <div>
          <a href="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3663057.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox">
            <img data-lazy="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3663057.jpg" alt="Image 1">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661267.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox">
            <img data-lazy="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661267.jpg" alt="Image 2">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661194.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox">
            <img data-lazy="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661194.jpg" alt="Image 3">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661227.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox">
            <img data-lazy="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661227.jpg" alt="Image 4">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661259.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox">
            <img data-lazy="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661259.jpg" alt="Image 5">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661265.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox">
            <img data-lazy="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661265.jpg" alt="Image 6">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slider-thumbnails">
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3663057.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 1">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661267.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 2">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661194.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 3">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661227.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 4">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661259.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 5">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://www.bayustudio.com/files/articles/slick3/demo1/img/pexels-cottonbro-3661265.jpg" alt="Thumbnail 6">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="product-description">
      <h2>Product Title</h2>
      <p>
        <strong>Price:</strong> Rp 120.000
        <br />
        <strong>Brand:</strong> Lorem Ipsum
        <br />
        <strong>Weight:</strong> 2kg
      </p>
      <h3>Description</h3>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
      <p>
        Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.3/js/lightbox.min.js" integrity="sha512-k2GFCTbp9rQU412BStrcD/rlwv1PYec9SNrkbQlo6RZCf75l6KcC3UwDY8H5n5hl4v77IDtIPwOk9Dqjs/mMBQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Your ```html``` also had some stray end tags, which could just have been there by mistake in setting up the example to share, just letting you know in case. If not, run your file through: https://validator.w3.org/